# How to set style on Django Filter 'Safe'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have code like this.

```
...
<p style="font-size: 1.3rem; margin-top: 1.5rem; border: solid 1px #eaeaea; padding: 2rem; background-color: #efefff;">
   {{ object.content|safe}}
</p>
...
```

I expected it would set style on `object.content`. But what I got is the content went below styled tag `<p>` not inside it. Because `object.content` also has its tag `<p>`.

So how do I set style using safe filter?

Comment: Can't you just remove the <p> tag from the object content? or add a class to the <p> tag in the object.content and apply style to that class? or you can add the style or class to the <p> tag in the object.content after the page is rendered via jquery?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the comment. Anyway I have found the solution by setting outer tag `<p style='...'>` to `<div></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the paragraph tag with 'div' tag. Provide the font changes on that 'div' tag.

```
<div class="safe" style="font-size: 1.3rem; margin-top: 1.5rem; border: solid 1px #eaeaea; padding: 2rem; background-color: #efefff;">
  <p>
   {{ object.content|safe}}
</p>
</div>
```

This Will Work